# Accessing codebehind variable from frontend

Tags: asp.net

Right, so my simple question is

why can't I do this (assumnig someVariable is defined, of course)

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="<%= someVariable %>/styles/global.less" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: You can't because you'll receive an electric shock?

Comment: Make the `someVariable` public to access it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I will not agree, the duplicate is not the same question, the answer of Murali is closer to.

Comment: @Aristos: How do you know the reason? OP hasn't even mentioned an error. We can vote to reopen the question if OP adds more informations.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Is not so important to reopen because as you say the OP hasn't mention where the variable come from.

Comment: BTW I found a solution but dont know how to close the question - for whatever reason, when dealing with tags in <head>, this has to be done (notice the "" in the beginning of the asp code part):

<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="<%# "" + rootUrl%>/styles/global.less" type="text/css" />

Answer (score 0):

it is possible if you define it as `public`

```
public class MyPage:System.web.UI.Page
{
 public string someVariable;
 ...
}
```

Then

```
href="<%= someVariable %>/styles/global.less"
```